# Change Frame of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to modify the frame of a `UIImageView` when a specific rotation happens, but when i change it the UIImage inside the `UIImageView` doesn't look affected, and if i NSLog the `UIImageView` frame size its changed, but its not reflected on the view, why this happens?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *couponBg;

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
     if ((UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(fromInterfaceOrientation)) &&
         UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight == [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])         {
         self.couponBg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.couponBg.frame.size.width, self.couponBg.frame.size.height);
         NSLog(@"FRAME:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.couponBg.frame));
         self.couponBg.frame = CGRectZero;
         NSLog(@"FRAME:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.couponBg.frame));
     }
 }
```

I get the correct frame sizes in NSLog:

> 2013-11-23 17:05:00.674 -----[10302:70b] FRAME:{{0, 0}, {320, 199}}
>
> 2013-11-23 17:05:00.674 -----[10302:70b] FRAME:{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

But in the view the Image is always the same size ? Why is this happening?

Comment: I think the most likely culprit is that you haven't actually assigned the `UIImageView` that has been added to your view to `self.couponBg` Can you verify that you have done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the CGATransform and Autolayout when i did the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from apple UIView documentations:

> autoresizesSubviews A Boolean value that determines whether the
>   receiver automatically resizes its subviews when its bounds change.
>   @property(nonatomic) BOOL autoresizesSubviews When set to YES, the
>   receiver adjusts the size of its subviews when its bounds change. The
>   default value is YES.

You should make sure this value is set up in your UIImageView and you should set your UIImage.autoresizingMask to right value.

Comment: I added     self.couponBg.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.couponBg.autoresizesSubviews = YES; But i get the same result. I dont know what you are saying with UIImage.autoresizingMask cause UIImage hasn't this property.